# Issues configuring consul with Chef execute resource

Tags: chef-infra, consul

I have a cookbook that will completely configure a client node to use consul with the exception of joining the client to the cluster. The following command is failing:

```
execute "join consul" do
  command "/usr/local/bin/consul join #{consul_server}"
  action :nothing
end
```

Running what I think is the same command on the instance itself however works after the cookbook has failed:

```
/usr/local/bin/consul join server-001.flapjacks.com
```

The service is set up via a systemd script that sets the config to: /etc/consul.d

```
[Unit]
Description="HashiCorp Consul - A service mesh solution"
Documentation=https://www.consul.io/
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/consul.d/consul.hcl

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/consul agent -config-dir /etc/consul.d
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/consul reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When checked the service is running properly.

The execute resource is triggered by a template resource:

```
template '/etc/consul.d/webserver.json' do
  source 'webserver.json.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
  action :create
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "consul")
  notifies :run, "execute[join consul]"
end
```

The chef run output errors with this:

```
STDERR: Error joining address 'server-001.flapjacks.com': Put http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/join/server-001.flapjacks.com: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connect: connection refused
       Failed to join any nodes.
```

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: I've got around this issue with using "start_join" in the consul.hcl config file. It still does not explain why I can't run this command in chef however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suggests that consul itself on the node is not running. I see it could be because you do notify the consul restart on template change and both the notifies 
- consul restart
- join execute 
runs parallely and thus the join commands fails complaining about consul not reachable on localhost itself.

Reference :
[image: consul help instructions]